# Inserting id column in new table

Tags: java, sql-server

I have situation like this.

1. I need to read data from a table. Let's say this table is called `Person_Old` and has three columns

[image]

2. I need to read the data from `Person_Old` and to save in another table called `Person_New`. In the `Person_New` table, I need to insert an extra column called `ID`. So in the `Person_New` table, I have a total of 4 columns.

The new table should be like this:

[image]

3. I have a Java class Called Person. where i have three fields firstname, lastname and dateOfBirth. Now if i insert another field called id like below

   @ID

   @GeneratedValue

   private Long id;

then I get an error

> Invalid column name ID

So now my question is how to insert this `id` column in my java class and in the SQL script for creating `Person_new` table so that when I run the program it'll read the data from old table and while persisting data in new table it'll generate Ids for each entry.

I would be grateful for your suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: do you need to generate the ID on the client? SQL Server has an `identity` property for this very reason.

Answer (score 0):

You should define the column name and Primary key annotation need to be corrected.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column("ID")
private Long id;
```